# Reloading a page and sending new post data, but keeping old post data also

Tags: php, sql, post

I have a search feature on site that displays several sets of data. I want to sort it with new post data, but keep the old post data when reloading the same page.

So that is to say, on page.php for example - I run a search. It is looking for apples and oranges from different venders.

So the post data in my check list says Post apples and oranges.

Now the page reloads, having got the information that I'm looking for apples and oranges - it goes off to the database and drags all the relevant vendors and their products to the page.

That is where I am with this at the moment.

Now my dilemma. I want to add a link at the top of page.php that says "Order by price". And one that says "Order by date posted".

By default the sql query is ordered by date so already appear by date.

Now my idea to resolve this, was to create a link that let me post to the exact same page. So in php I could get that data (call it ORDER)

```
if (isset($_POST['Order'])){
    $theOrder = $_POST['Order'];
}
else {
    $theOrder = 'Date Desc';
}
```

Now on my earlier script, I can have a statement that goes something like:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE name = '$products'
    ORDER BY '$theOrder'";
```

(no bind here just for simplicity)

The thing is having reloaded the same page with the new post, Order - i've now lost the original post $_POST['Products'] which I passed into $products.

Is there a way to keep that original post information and simply add to/change $theOrder on page reload?

Comment: use GET requests instead of post, submit the search term and order by vars in same request. Otherwise you'll have to use cookies and or session vars.

Comment: You have sql injection.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone he said: '(no bind here just for simplicity)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store this data into a session, and retrieve it later. Or you can add the original post data into a hidden input field, and then when the form is submitted a second time, you will have the original data, as well as the new data.

Answer (score 1):

just add a hidden field to your submission form containing the old data

```
<input type='hidden' name='Products' value='" . $_POST['Products'] . "' />
```

This way they will be accessible with `$_POST['Products']`again just like before